CSS not loading when importing UMD into ESM file
I'm transpiling a React component library into UMD using Webpack (Babel, etc.). The components load just fine in a local Storybook instance, but when I import them into a new create-react-app project, none of the styles load...or classes for that matter. I can see what appears to be the CSS and class names in the built JS file, but the elements in the DOM look like this when inspected:
<h1 class>Hello World!</h1>

Is there a trick to getting them to load? I've tried just about every possible Webpack configuration I could come up with to no avail. Regardless, here are some of the files in question:
Library/webpack.config
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        HelloWorld: './src/components/HelloWorld/index.js',
    },
    externals: {
        'react': 'react',
        'react-dom': 'react-dom',
    },
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            [
                                '@babel/preset-react',
                                {
                                    runtime: 'automatic',
                                },
                            ],
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.module.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    outputPath: (url, resourcePath, context) => {
                        const componentName = resourcePath.replace(context, '').split('/')[3];

                        return `${componentName}/${url}`;
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: '@svgr/webpack',
                options: {
                    exportType: 'named',
                },
            }
        ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name]/index.js',
        library: {
            type: 'umd',
        },
        path: `${__dirname}/build`,
    },
};

Library/package.json
{
    ...
    "exports": {
        "./HelloWorld": "./build/HelloWorld/index.js"
    }
    ...
  },
}

Library/src/components/HelloWorld/index.js
import styles from './HelloWorld.module.css';

export default function HelloWorld() {
    return {
        <h1 className={styles.helloWorld}>Hello World!</h1>
    }
}

Library/src/components/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.module.css
.helloWorld {
    color: red;
}

Project/src/App/index.js
import HelloWorld from 'my-library/HelloWorld';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <HelloWorld /> 
    )
}


For anyone interested, adding esModule: false to both the CSS loaders' options in the Webpack config. solved it  ¯_(ツ)_/¯
...
{
    loader: 'style-loader',
    options: {
        esModule: false,
    },
},
{
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
        esModule: false,
        modules: true,
    },
},
...

